# Paypal checkout js not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, paypal

I'm developing an e commerce website using `angularjs` in which I'm using **paypal checkout** https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/script-option... for `paypal` integration. When a user click's `paypal` rendered button, it is supposed to open a new popup window in which `paypal` login and payment is made, and then user is redirected to our app with payment details. The app seems to work fine in chrome, edge and even IE for that matter (although IE has different issue with the flow), but in **firefox**, the popup modal is **not** triggering at all. **No console errors**, which has made it very difficult to solve. Made a lot of research (google search :-p) but couldn't fix it. Please anyone help me, thanks.

Here is my script js for `paypal`

```
// Paypal
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // Environment: 'sandbox' or 'production'
    // Pass the client ids to use to create your transaction on sandbox and production environments
    client: {
        sandbox: 'xxxxxx', // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
        production: 'xxxxxx' // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
    },
    // Pass the payment details for your transaction
    // See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create for the expected json parameters
    payment: function() {
        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [{
                amount: {
                    total: 25.00,
                    currency: 'USD'
                }
                     }]
        });
    },
    // Display a "Pay Now" button rather than a "Continue" button
    commit: true,
    // Pass a function to be called when the customer completes the payment
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            console.log('The payment was completed!');
        });
    },
    // Pass a function to be called when the customer cancels the payment
    onCancel: function(data) {
        // console.log('The payment was cancelled!');
    }
}, '#paypal');
```

And html for rendering button

```
<button type="button" id="paypal"></button>
```

Comment: Hey, I can try to help you with this. Can you let me know your firefox version, your OS, and if possible can you try to host your button somewhere so I can try. Please also let me know if this button works for you in firefox: http://www.bluesuncorp.co.uk/icv4/sandbox.htm

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. My firefox version is "52.0.1 (32-bit)" and OS is "Windows 10 (64 bit)". I tried your app in firefox and it works!. So probably it has something to do with the angular js. I have created sample paypal app in angularjs and deployed on heroku http://paypalshop.herokuapp.com. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Can I suggest trying the native angular element? https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#angularjs-element

Comment: It WORKS!. I can't believe that small change made it work for firefox. Just by rendering paypal button using paypal directive made it work. I don't understand why that was not a problem in chrome but only in firefox. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. :-)